# Trying to write a CSV record has the error "the trait `std::convert::AsRef<[u8]>` is not implemented for `u8`"

Tags: csv, rust

Here's a minimal repro:

```
extern crate csv;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

fn do_write(writer: &mut csv::Writer<File>, buf: &[u8]) {
    // The error is coming from this line
    writer.write_record(buf);
}

fn main() {
    let mut writer = csv::Writer::from_path(r"c:\temp\file.csv").unwrap();
    let str = "Hello, World!".to_string();
    do_write(&mut writer, str.as_bytes());
}
```

Which causes a compilation error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `u8: std::convert::AsRef<[u8]>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:7:16
  |
7 |         writer.write_record(buf);
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::AsRef<[u8]>` is not implemented for `u8`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::AsRef<[u8]>` for `&u8`
```

What does this error mean? It seems that I'm already passing a `u8` slice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review the signature for `write_record`:

```
fn write_record<I, T>(&mut self, record: I) -> Result<()> 
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    T: AsRef<[u8]>,
```

It expects something that can become an **iterator** of values. You are providing a `&[u8]`, which *is* an iterator, but only of `&u8` values. The error is that these `&u8`s do not implement `AsRef<[u8]>`.

You can wrap the single passed-in string in another array to create something that can act as an iterator:

```
writer.write_record(&[buf]);
```